# Length variable in netcdf file

Tags: variable

I am trying to know the length of a variable 'i' in a netcdf file '122009.nc'. This is my script so far:

```
#!bin/bash
var=ncdump -v i 122009.nc
var_length=${#var}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line :

```
var=ncdump -v i 122009.nc
```

needs to be:

```
var=$(ncdump -v i 122009.nc)
```

This will allow the result of the command to be read into var and later used to find the length